# ng2-date-picker: node_modules/ng2-date-picker/ng2-date-picker.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol NavigationTabModule

Tags: angular

I have angular-cli 1.5.6 when i clone an angular 4 project after runing `npm install` and when serving the project using `ng serve` I got this error with `ng2-date-picker`

```
ERROR in C:/Users/.../node_modules/ng2-date-picker/common/types/selection-evet.enum..d.ts (2,13): In ambient enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression.

ERROR in C:/Users/.../node_modules/ng2-date-picker/common/types/selection-evet.enum..d.ts (3,17): In ambient enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression.

ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module C:/Users/.../node_modules/ng2-date-picker/ng2-date-picker.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol NavigationTabModule in C:/Users/.../src/app/navigation-tab/navigation-tab.module.ts, resolving symbol NavigationTabModule in C:/Users/.../src/app/navigation-tab/navigation-tab.module.ts
```

In `package.json` file I have `"ng2-date-picker": "^2.8.1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that fixed my problem is getting rid of the `^` in ng2-date-picker version in `package.json`

Replacing `"ng2-date-picker": "^2.8.1"` to `"ng2-date-picker": "2.8.1"` fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

this way work for me:

1. remove `node-modules`
2. run command `npm audit fix --only-dev --force`
3. in `package.json` rollback `highlight.js` & `@angular-devkit/build-angular` to your old version
4. run command `npm i jalali-moment`
5. `ng s`